# Clear x icon focus out issue using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I need x icon for removing input field values 
1. When user type anything "x" icon will be displayed

2. If no values available in input box x will be hide
3. When values available in input box and focus out the input box we need to hide the x icon and focus in we need to show x icon again.

When we add `ng-blur="count = !count"` (Focus out i need to hide x if input has values) in input box my expectation will be failed.

**CODE:**

```
<span ng-show="name && count" ng-click="name=''" style="position: absolute;left: 203px;cursor;pointer;">X</span>
Name: <input ng-model="name" ng-focus="count = !count" ng-init="count=false" >
<p>{{count}}</p>
```

Any one please helps me how to fix this issue

Comment: You could do `ng-focus="count=true"` and `ng-blur="count=false"` to show and hide "x" icon

Comment: @PankajParkar : we already tried this option but when we click x icon value will not be removed

Comment: @PankajParkar: I tried nothing happened

Comment: Please provide a snippet that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @gyc : https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/3129/

Comment: @PankajParkar: we found soluion , copied below solution below

Answer (score 1):

There's something wrong with jsfiddle. The snippet below (copy pasted from your question) works fine.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name="";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<span ng-show="name && count" ng-click="name=''" style="position: absolute;left: 203px;">X</span>

Name: <input ng-model="name" ng-focus="count = !count" ng-init="count=false" ng-blur="count = !count">

<p>{{count}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span ng-show="name && count" ng-click="name=''" 
style="position:absolute;left: 203px;cursor;pointer;">
   X
</span>

Name: <input ng-model="name" ng-focus="count = !count" ng-blur="count!=count" ng-init="count=false" >
<p>{{count}}</p>
```

Comment: When we focus out and focus in  input box and try to click x the value will not be removed .

Answer (score 0):

The **click** event fires after **blur**, so the list is being hidden before you are able to click it. The simple solution is to use **mousedown** event instead of click:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<span ng-show="name && count" ng-click="name=''" ng-mousedown="name=''" style="position: absolute;left: 203px;">X</span>

Name: <input ng-model="name" ng-focus="count = !count" ng-init="count=false" ng-blur="count = !count">

<p>{{count}}</p>
```